What is the significance of pomegranate fruit and its design to Judaism and Christianity?
We read in Exodus 28:31-34( KJV):

And thou shalt make the robe of the ephod all of blue..........And there shall be an hole in the top of it, in the midst thereof: it shall have a binding of woven work And beneath upon the hem of it thou shalt make pomegranates of blue, and of purple, and of scarlet, round about the hem thereof; and bells of gold between them round about: A golden bell and a pomegranate, a golden bell and a pomegranate, upon the hem of the robe round about.

OT mentions the name of pomegranate 25 times, most of which relate to pattern or design. Even though apple finds a mention in Joel 1:12,  pomegranate seems have dominated over all other fruits.
The image of Madonna of Pomegranate also pictures Infant Jesus holding a pomegranate .
My question therefore,  is : what is the significance of pomegranate fruit and its design to Judaism and Christianity ?

This question is similar to: What's the significance of pomegranates?. Does this answer your question?

Thanks, Jason_. The linked question and the answers thereto explain to a great extent, the OT significance and to a small extent, to the NT. But if someone can give inputs on Madonna of the Pomegranate and the fruit that Jesus holds, it will complete the answers.
